# cant pass a value from dropdownlistfor to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

here is my `GET` controller.

```
public ActionResult UppgiftsSida2(int? idet)
    {

        Uppgifter uppgiften;
        if (idet.HasValue)
        {
            uppgiften = db.Uppgifters.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UppgifterID == idet);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index", "Home");
        }

        int tillhörgrupp = Convert.ToInt32(uppgiften.TillhörGrupp.GruppID);
        Grupp gruppen = db.Grupps.SingleOrDefault(g => g.GruppID == tillhörgrupp);
        ICollection<AnvändarKonton> medlemmar = gruppen.GruppMedlemmar;

        //prövar med viewmodel
        var gruppviewmodel = new GruppViewModel();
        gruppviewmodel.grupp = gruppen;
        gruppviewmodel.uppgift = uppgiften;
        gruppviewmodel.medlemmar = medlemmar;            
        gruppviewmodel.ledareID = gruppen.LedareID;
        List<SelectListItem> namnen = new List<SelectListItem>();


        foreach (var item in medlemmar)
        {

           namnen.Add(new SelectListItem{ Value = item.AnvändarID.ToString(), Text = item.HelaNamnet });

        }
        gruppviewmodel.lemmar = new SelectList(namnen, "Value", "Text");


        return View(gruppviewmodel);
    }
```

and heres the viewmodel.

```
   public class GruppViewModel
{
    public virtual Uppgifter uppgift { get; set; }
    public virtual Grupp grupp { get; set; }
    public virtual int ledareID { get; set; }
    public virtual AnvändarKonton användare { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AnvändarKonton> medlemmar { get; set; }

    public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList lemmar { get; set; }

}
```

and the razor-piece where i want to pick from a dropdownlistfor.

```
  using (Html.BeginForm("läggtillanvändaretilluppgift", "Uppgifter", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <dt>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <div class="form-group">


                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.användare.AnvändarID.ToString(), Model.lemmar, "Välj en fårskalle", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "vald", @value = "AnvändarID",  })
                @Html.DropDownList()
            </div>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <input type="submit" id="Submit1" value="Lägg till" />
        </dt>
    }
```

my `post` controller looks like this.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult läggtillanvändaretilluppgift([Bind(Include = "AnvändarID")]AnvändarKonton anv)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("UppgiftsSida");
    }
```

problem is, nothing ever gets posted. I have tried a bunch of possible solution. now I have almost given up. please help if you've got any answers

Comment: I think the problem is with .ToString() method in your Html.DropDownListFor lambda parameter. I doubt it will bind back to the right property that way.

Comment: yeah you're right! it wont. i realise right now that i took a snapshot of the code at the wrong time! i have tried a bunch of different lambda expressions, but they wont work either!

Comment: You have multiple problems. First creating a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> from the first one using `new SelectList(..)` is pointless (property `lemmar` should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` not `SelectList`. You cannot use `.ToString()` as noted above. Your creating a a dropdownlist for a control name `användare.AnvändarID` but you exclude that from binding by using a `Bind` attribute only includes a property named `AnvändarID` which does not exist in your view or model.

Comment: Your editing view data so the first step if to create a view model, and view models do not contain properties which are data models - just the properties of a model(s) that you want to display/edit in the view. When using a view model you never need a `Bind` attribute. And finally the model in the POST method signature needs to be the same as the model in the view.

Comment: allright!! a million thanks! now it works! this is my first time using dropdownfor, and your help did really help out a lot =)